# Прописная буква после запятой

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Попалось название статьи ["Смертельное блюдо, Или как не нужно писать рецепты"](http://yagazeta.com/news.php?extend.44641.55) (кстати, всем очень советую почитать - там как раз о грамотности и неграмотности в интернете). Но меня интересует: уместна ли тут прописная буква после запятой?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если имя собственное состоит из двух названий, соединяемых союзом ИЛИ, то первое слово второго названия также пишется с прописной буквы, например: «Дон Жуан, или Каменный гость».
Соответственно, надо  писать:  "Смертельное блюдо, или Как не нужно писать рецепты"

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что что-то тут не так))) А статья и правда отличная!